# How old is Lumiere from Beauty and the Beast?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

How old is Lumiere from *Beauty and the Beast*? I've tried to search it up but it doesn't come up.

Comment: I've removed the second question about Chip as that should really be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

No *canonical* age is given for this character but we can certainly pick an approximate upper and lower bound based on the age of the individuals chosen to portray his character, e.g. **something around 35–50 years of age.**

---

In the [1991 version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast_(1991_film)) he's voiced by Jerry Orbach who was **56 years old at the time of filming** but renowned for his vocal range and young-sounding voice. Visually his character appears to be in his late 30s or early 40s.

[image]

In the [2017 version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_and_the_Beast_(2017_film)) he's played by Ewan McGregor who was **aged 46 at the time of filming**.

[image]

- In the official musical versions, he has been played by Gary Beach (46) and John Tartaglia (28)
- Disney put out a casting call in 2019 for new actors for a revised stage musical of Beauty and the Beast, specifying actors ages between twenty and fifty years of age. .

> Lumiere (Supporting): **Male, 20–50**
>
> The French butler who was transformed into a Candelabrum. He is light-hearted, suave, romantic, smooth-talking, and charming. He has a romantic involvement with Babette. This character speaks with a French accent. This role requires strong character acting, and he should move well. Vocal range: Tenor/Baritone (A–High F#)